# ReactJS - Calling setState inside for loop, updating the state and displaying the result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, setstate

I have an array of data that I wanna call with axios, I'm not using axios.all because I want to know the progress of each request and with axios.all the method is call after all request are finished, I want to display something like 15/50 requests remaining.

The requests inside the for loop works, but calling setState only renders one time, I know setState is async and due to performance issues I think React is not calling setState that many times.

My real problem is updating the state of react inside the for loop and updating the JSX.

Here's a CodeSandbox of the for loop problem:  https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-field-mdodx?file=/src/App.js:0-597

And here's the gist of the upload method and the way I make the requests:

```
  uploadRecords = async () => {
    const { recordsUpdated } = this.state
    const { recordData } = this.props

    for (const record of recordData) {
      const response = await createRecord(tenant) //Method of axios
      this.setState({ recordsUpdated: [...recordsUpdated, response] })
    }}
```

And here's the JSX:

```
         <div>
            <p className="alert-description text-center">
              Please wait and do not leave the page while we upload the records
            </p>
            <p className="alert-description text-center">
             Uploading: {recordsUpdated.length}/{totalRecords}
            </p>
            <div className="progress-container">
              <p className="text-muted">{recordsUpdated.length}%</p>
              <Progress color="info" value={recordsUpdated.length} />
            </div>
          </div>
```

All the records are uploaded with no problem, but the state only shows 1 update.

I'll appreciate all feedback and different approaches

Comment: You probably are updating state using old state. try the `this.setState((currentState)=>{recordsUpdated: [...currentState.recordsUpdated, response]}` approach, which uses the state when the update happens, which is less likely to overwrite state with old state.

Comment: In the sandbox code you shared, you haven't defined your width state in the constructor and the for loop is never initialized. Fixing these will let your code work

Comment: @KaranSingh yeah my bad fixing it didn't work as I expected.

Comment: Updating the state like you suggested  @GarrettMotzner solve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
this.setState({ recordsUpdated: [...recordsUpdated, response] });
```

to:

```
this.setState((currentState) => { recordsUpdated: [...currentState.recordsUpdated, response]};
```